# how to sign CSR using pkcs11 wrapper ECDSA key

Tags: java, cryptography, pkcs#11

i want to generate ECDSA keypair in pkcs11 usb token. after that want to sign CSR with private key, but facing exception "Invalid signature".

```
Mechanism keyPairGenerationMechanism = Mechanism.get(PKCS11Constants.CKM_EC_KEY_PAIR_GEN);
 ECDSAPrivateKey ecdsaPrivateKeyTemplate = new ECDSAPrivateKey();
ecdsaPrivateKeyTemplate.getLabel().setCharArrayValue(keyAlias.toCharArray());
   ecdsaPrivateKeyTemplate.getId().setByteArrayValue(keyAlias.getBytes());
   ecdsaPrivateKeyTemplate.getSign().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
   ecdsaPrivateKeyTemplate.getDecrypt().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
   ecdsaPrivateKeyTemplate.getToken().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
   ecdsaPrivateKeyTemplate.getPrivate().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
   ecdsaPrivateKeyTemplate.getSensitive().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
  ecdsaPrivateKeyTemplate.getExtractable().setBooleanValue(Boolean.FALSE);
   ecdsaPrivateKeyTemplate.getKeyType().setLongValue(PKCS11Constants.CKK_EC); ECDSAPublicKey ecdsaPublicKeyTemplate = new ECDSAPublicKey();    ecdsaPublicKeyTemplate.getLabel().setCharArrayValue(keyAlias.toCharArray());
    ecdsaPublicKeyTemplate.getId().setByteArrayValue(keyAlias.getBytes());
    ecdsaPublicKeyTemplate.getEncrypt().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
   ecdsaPublicKeyTemplate.getPrivate().setBooleanValue(Boolean.FALSE);
    ecdsaPublicKeyTemplate.getVerify().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
   ecdsaPublicKeyTemplate.getToken().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);

 ecdsaPublicKeyTemplate.getKeyType().setLongValue(PKCS11Constants.CKK_EC);
    ecdsaPublicKeyTemplate.getModifiable().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);

    ASN1ObjectIdentifier curveId = getCurveId((getEcdsaParamsOID(256)));
X962Parameters x962 = new X962Parameters(curveId);
   byte[] paramsBytes = x962.getEncoded();
    ecdsaPublicKeyTemplate.getEcdsaParams().setByteArrayValue(paramsBytes);
    KeyPair generatedKeyPair = m_objSession.generateKeyPair(keyPairGenerationMechanism,ecdsaPublicKeyTemplate, ecdsaPrivateKeyTemplate);


   ECDSAPublicKey publicKey = (ECDSAPublicKey) generatedKeyPair.getPublicKey();

    ECDSAPrivateKey privateKey = (ECDSAPrivateKey) generatedKeyPair.getPrivateKey();
 byte[] pubPoint = publicKey.getEcPoint().getByteArrayValue();
    DEROctetString os = (DEROctetString) DEROctetString.fromByteArray(pubPoint);
    AlgorithmIdentifier keyAlgID = new AlgorithmIdentifier(
            X9ObjectIdentifiers.id_ecPublicKey, curveId);
    SubjectPublicKeyInfo pkInfo = new SubjectPublicKeyInfo(keyAlgID, os.getOctets());
```

---

Signing code from comments:

```
ECDSAPrivateKey signatureKey = this.getECDSAPrivateKey(a_strKeyId,m_objSession);

MessageDigest digestEngine = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
digestEngine.update(bUnsignedData);
byte[] digest = digestEngine.digest();

Mechanism signatureMechanism = Mechanism.get(PKCS11Constants.CKM_ECDSA);
m_objSession.signInit(signatureMechanism, signatureKey);

DigestInfo digestInfoEngine = new DigestInfo(a_objAlgorithmIdentifier, digest);
byte[] digestInfo = digestInfoEngine.getEncoded();

byte[] signatureValue = m_objSession.sign(digestInfo);
```

Comment: The output of signing a CSR is a certificate. If you are not using any JCE library like bouncycastle, you will have to construct the certificate data, and then sign the certificate data to give out a valid certificate. And only if you post more details to your question, like a runnable code snippet, people will be able help you easily.

Comment: i have generated ecdsa keypair in pkcs11 token. now trying to get private and public key to generate CSR. but when i decode CSR, it shows invalid signature. i am using bouncy castle

Comment: you need to show some sample code for people to identify what you are doing wrong.

Comment: ECDSAPrivateKey signatureKey = this.getECDSAPrivateKey(a_strKeyId,m_objSession);
 MessageDigest digestEngine = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); digestEngine.update(bUnsignedData);
byte[] digest = digestEngine.digest();
Mechanism signatureMechanism =Mechanism.get(PKCS11Constants.CKM_ECDSA);
m_objSession.signInit(signatureMechanism, signatureKey);
DigestInfo digestInfoEngine = new DigestInfo(a_objAlgorithmIdentifier, digest);
            byte[] digestInfo = digestInfoEngine.getEncoded();
            byte[] signatureValue = m_objSession.sign(digestInfo);

Comment: @always_a_rookie_to_learn: that's a common error but quite wrong. A CSR is signed by the _requester_ keypair. A cert body is NOT the same as the CSR body; it contains _some_ of the CSR data but not all, plus a lot of data that is not from the CSR. The cert is signed by the _CA_ keypair.

Comment: Rukhsana FYI: any JCA `PublicKey` provides its SPKI-encoding, so you can just do `SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance (publicKey.getEncoded())`

Comment: i am creating ECDSA keys using iaik pkcs#11 wrapper. and in case of ECDSA, we dont have publicKey.getEncoded().

Answer (score 2):

For ECDSA you don't need `DigestInfo`, the digest value (in bytes) is signed directly. `DigestInfo` is probably required for RSA.

Comment: can you share some code, i have directly signed without using digest info but issue is still same. did you check my code above?

Comment: I haven't coded this myself. This is just from my base knowledge of ECDSA; it doesn't contain an ASN.1 structure like RSA / PKCS#1 (if just because it would not fit). To be fair, I will probably not try this either if the question is formatted like it is / was.

Comment: ECDSAPrivateKey signatureKey  = privateKey;//this.getECDSAPrivateKey(a_strKeyId, m_objSession)   
          Mechanism signatureMechanism = Mechanism.get(PKCS11Constants.CKM_ECDSA);
            m_objSession.signInit(signatureMechanism, signatureKey);
            byte[] signatureValue = m_objSession.sign(bUnsignedData);

Comment: No, because you still need to hash the data as you're using "raw" ECDSA. You just don't need the `DigestInfo` structure around it.